# Why doesn't my local storage work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, local-storage

I am trying to localStore the history but it does not work. I tried JSON.stringify and a script called JStorage but I couldn't get either to work.

```
function updateHistory(video) {
getHistory();
blacklist[video["id"]] = true;
myhistory.push(video);
var html = "<li class=\"history\">" +
    "<img class= \"img-rounded\" src=\"{0}\"/>" +
    "<p><b title=\"{2}\"><a class=\"extendedLink\" href=\"javascript:watchHistoricVideo(\'{1}\');\"><span></span>{2}</a></b><br>" +
    "by {3}<br>" +
    "{4} | {5} views</p>" +
    "</li>";

$("#myhistory").prepend(html.format(video["thumbnail"],
    video["id"],
    video["title"],
    video["uploader"],
    video["length"],
    video["views"]));
saveHistory();
}

function saveHistory() {
localStorage.setItem(myhistory, myhistory.innerHTML);
}
```

(The alert does show up)

```
function getHistory() {
localStorage.getItem(myhistory);
alert("working");
}
```

Comment: Define "does not work." What exactly is `getHistory()` supposed to do, anyway?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage

Comment: myhistory is an array. Why are you using .innerHTML on it? You didn't pass a string name to be used as the localstorage item name.

Comment: `getHistory()` doesn't actually return a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is, instead of storing the html part you better store the `video` object instead, you can store videos based on their `id`, and instead of array use javascript object:

```
function setVideo(video) {
    var videos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myhistory") || "{}");
    videos[video["id"]]=video;
    localStorage.setItem("myhistory", JSON.stringify(videos));
}
function getVideos() {
    var myhistory = localStorage.getItem("myhistory");
    if(!myhistory) return {};
    else return JSON.parse(myhistory);
}
function getVideo(id) {
    var myhistory = localStorage.getItem("myhistory");
    if(!myhistory) return null;
    var videos = JSON.parse(myhistory);
    return videos[id] || null;
}
```

now you can use `getVideo` to retrieve the video object by id.you can separate the part which shows the video, like:

```
function showVideo(video) {
    blacklist[video["id"]] = true;
    var html = "<li class=\"history\">" +
        "<img class= \"img-rounded\" src=\"{0}\"/>" +
        "<p><b title=\"{2}\"><a class=\"extendedLink\" href=\"javascript:watchHistoricVideo(\'{1}\');\"><span></span>{2}</a></b><br>" +
        "by {3}<br>" +
        "{4} | {5} views</p>" +
        "</li>";

    $("#myhistory").prepend(html.format(video["thumbnail"],
    video["id"],
    video["title"],
    video["uploader"],
    video["length"],
    video["views"]));
}
```

let's say you want to show the whole videos in the history:

```
var videos = getVideos();
for(var id in videos){
    showVideo(videos[id]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would I use getVideo to make the video show up in the array next time the user uses the site?